# seeding srandom with char buffer

Tags: c, hash, random

I need to generate a seed from a hash of a string . This seed is going to be used to generate random numbers, I will probably used srandom(), however this function doesn't take as an argument a char buffer it takes an integer. Is there any way I can seed srandom using a char buffer or is there any other way I can generate an int seed from a hash key. Hope you can help!

Comment: What's the hash value's type?

Comment: I'm using MD5 to hash it, the output is returned in a char type buffer

Comment: Are you after strong security, or just a quick hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *hashKey = "helloWorld!"; /* your Hash pointer */

int intHash = 0;
int hashCarry = 0;
for(int i = 0; hashKey[i] != '\0'; i++){

    intHash ^= hashKey[i];  // XORing with current character

    hashCarry = intHash & 0xF0000000; /* getting 4 bits - MSBs */

    intHash <<= 4; // Multiplying it by 16 

    intHash += hashCarry >> 28; /* e.g 0xF0000000 becomes 0x0000000F */
}

srandom(intHash);
```

Hope this helps...

The above Code will not destroy any of your HashKey bit.

Answer (score 0):

Is parsing a string into a number what you're looking for? If so, try this:

```
char buf[] = "12345678";
int number = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
srand(number);
```

Edit: from your comment:

> I'm using MD5 to hash it

And you want to get back the value you hashed? Then you're missing the fundamental concept of hashing. You can't get back a hashed value from a hash, that's the point.

Comment: I deleted my answer, looking for better one, but what's the problem with the `sscanf` I used which you are doing with `strtol` sorry , but can you plz little elaborate ?

Comment: @Omkant `sscanf(buffer, "%d", number);` will invoke undefined behavior since `scanf()` needs a pointer to its output arguments. The `strtol()` function is the standard way of string-to-integer conversion.

Comment: Ok got it I shoul have used `&number`, Thanks

Comment: I wanna know how to use the hashed value as seed for the random function

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't post any code you have so far, I'm making a couple of assumptions here.

```
char *strHash = "ABCD1234"; // could be anything, i.e. "HelloWorld!"

int intNumberFromHash = 0;
for(int intCurrentCharacter = 0; strHash[intCurrentCharacter] != '\0'; intCurrentCharacter++){
    intNumberFromHash <<= 8; // effectively multiply by 256
    intNumberFromHash += strHash[intCurrentCharacter];
}

srandom(intNumberFromHash);
```

This code will generate a "number" from a "string". However, it's not very smart (i.e. it will overflow often, ending up with only the last four characters really doing anything). If the hash is a hexadecimal value, you'd probably want to do something like this.

```
sscanf(theHash,"%x",number);
srandom(number);
```

The `%x` modifier will convert a hexadecimal value with lowercase values (i.e. "abcd1234"). `%X` will do uppercase hex ("ABCD1234").

Answer (score 0):

You could use initstate(3), or did I miss something?